# How to replace color with another color in a polygon?

Tags: netlogo

I have patches as follows:
[image]

I would like to color white patches as in this figure: [image]

Here my code to color white patches in blue:

```
ask patches with [pcolor = white] [
if any? neighbors with [pcolor = blue] [set pcolor blue] ]
```

But the problem is that I obtain this figure: [image].

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alan is right about the cause of your problem, but you don't need to create a `next-pcolor` patch variable. If you put both conditions inside the `with` block, NetLogo will *first* construct the agentset of patches, *and then* ask these patches to do stuff, thereby avoiding the timing problem that you had. Let's try it. And since you're obviously going to have to do it with both blue and cyan patches, let's build a more general version:

```
to color-white-patches-v1 [ c ]
  ask patches with [ pcolor = white and any? neighbors with [ pcolor = c ]] [
    set pcolor c
  ]
end
```

That you can then call with:

```
color-white-patches-v1 cyan
color-white-patches-v1 blue
```

Here is the result:

[image: v1]

But it's not quite what you wanted. That's because [`neighbors`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#neighbors) gives you all 8 neighbors of a patch. Let's try with `neighbors4` instead:

```
to color-white-patches-v2 [ c ]
  ask patches with [ pcolor = white and any? neighbors4 with [ pcolor = c ]] [
    set pcolor c
  ]
end
```

[image: v2]

Not quite there yet. It think you are going to have to resort to something like [`patch-at`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#patch-at). In this example, I look at only the patch above:

```
to color-white-patches-v3 [ c ]
  ask patches with [ pcolor = white and [ pcolor ] of patch-at 0 1 = c ] [
    set pcolor c
  ]
end
```

[image: v3]

I'm not sure if that was exactly what you wanted and how well that applies to your general problem, but with some combination of `patch-at`, you should be able to get what you need.

Comment: Thanks very much Nicolas. By using color-white-patches-v3, there is yet one white patch situated at the top in the second figure (color-white-patches-v2). Have I to test all possible combinations with patch-at (e.g. patch-at 0 1, patch-at 1 1, ....) ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm having a hard time identifying the "one white patch" you are referring to. But in any case, the answer is that you don't have to "test all possible combinations": if you understand what [`patch-at`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#patch-at) does, you should be able to figure out which one you need. You say your one extra white patch is "at the top": you could check, for example, if it has a blue patch below it (`patch-at 0 -1`) and on its right (`patch-at 1 0`).

Answer (score 2):

The problem arises because patches are being changed sequentially, so some white patches find they have new blue neighbors by the time they respond to `ask`.

```
ask patches with [pcolor = white and any? neighbors with [pcolor = blue]] [set pcolor blue]
```

Note: this answer is edited in response to Nicholas's observation that `with` will create the entire agent set before `ask` is called.  However I stuck with `neighbors` since that's how I read the question.