# How to replace color with another color in a rectangle?

Tags: netlogo

In the same optic than [How to replace color with another color in a polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082254/how-to-replace-color-with-another-color-in-a-polygon/25086601?noredirect=1#comment39071054_25086601), I would like to  replace white patches contained in the blue rectangles with blue patches:

I have blue rectangles as in the figure below :

[image]

I would like to have blue rectangles as follows:

[image]

By using `color-white-patches-v2 [ c ]` in [How to replace color with another color in a polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082254/how-to-replace-color-with-another-color-in-a-polygon/25086601?noredirect=1#comment39071054_25086601), I obtain this figure :

[image]

and by using `color-white-patches-v3 [ c ]` that I modified as follows (because I had this error message `OF expected input to be a turtle agentset or patch agentset or turtle or patch but got NOBODY instead.`:

```
to color-white-patches-v3  [c]
ask patches with [ pcolor = white] [
if (patch-at 0 1 != nobody and [pcolor] of patch-at 0 1 = c) or (patch-at 1 0 != nobody and [pcolor] of patch-at 1 0 = c) [
set pcolor c ] ]
end
```

I obtain:

[image]

I don't know how to get the figure 2 and to have a code which works for different polygon shapes.
Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this?

```
to color-white-patches
  ask patches with [ pcolor = white and count neighbors4 with [ pcolor = blue ] > 1 ] [
    set pcolor blue
  ]
end
```

This checks to see if the patches on at least two sides are blue. This should work for all the circumstances shown.

Comment: That's actually a much better answer than [the one I gave to the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25086601/487946).